# Button not posting back when shown in fancybox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

My button lbtnInsert posts back and so works correctly when I click it when my table is not shown in the fancybox lightbox. However, when the table is shown in the lightbox the button no longer works.
The codebhind for the button is never hit and no script errors show in my Chrome Console.

Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#viewtaskdetail').trigger('click');     
    });
</script>

<a id="viewtaskdetail" title="Task details" href="#addnewitem">Try now</a>


<div id="addnewitem">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:glossary,title %>" /></td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbTitle" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="100" ValidationGroup="inserttask" Width="400" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="errortext" ID="fdgRequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbTitle" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="<%$Resources:Glossary,required %>" ValidationGroup="inserttask" />
    </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="lbtnInsert" Text="<%$Resources:glossary,save %>" ValidationGroup="inserttask" CssClass="btn-primary" runat="server"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Found out that Fancybox like most JavaScript modals, moves it content to the end of the dom for display purposes. If you had form elements in content area, but the form outside, then after the dialog is display the elements are no longer children of the form.

Still not sure how I could work around that though...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to set parent to the first form, like this -

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    parent: "form:first" // Your jQuery selector
});
```

Comment: I updated my post with the apparent issue. I don't know where I should place your code sample, but would that solve the issue I found?